# Modifying (Draggable | jQuery UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

you know this link?

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

I think myself it's a good script. I wanted to modify it, so only top part is interactive, and could drag whole div, while rest won't be able to drag div. So here comes the come:

http://jsfiddle.net/fQ4us/

How to make it able to drag div with `Drag me around` text, but not with `Some outside content` text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make one of your div's a `handle` like in [this](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/draggable/handle.html) example